# Old rename was better for me

Tags: debian, package-management, rename

Debian now has a new `rename` that is different from the old `rename` written in Perl. Is it possible to install, aside of new `rename`, the old one? Which steps should I perform to install the old `rename`?

To address a comment, I specify that I'm using Debian unstable and that using `update-alternatives`

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config rename
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for rename
```

has been unhelpful. I've tried also

```
$ dpkg -S "$(readlink -f "$(command -v rename)")"
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern
```

but

```
$ dpkg -S "$(readlink -f "$(command -v rename.ul)")"
util-linux: /usr/bin/rename.ul
```

I forgot to mention that the binary (an ELF executable) is no more named `rename` (it has been renamed ahah).

Comment: There are many implementations of `rename`, many of which in `perl`, and the dumb one in util-linux in C. Which one do you get on your _new Debian system_? I still have `perl` a perl one. Maybe it's just a matter of running `update-alternative --config rename`. What problem do you have with that new rename whichever it is?

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg -S "$(readlink -f "$(command -v rename)")"`? And `apt-cache policy` on the corresponding package?

Comment: As far as I can tell, [`rename` is still a `perl` one on Debian unstable](https://packages.debian.org/sid/rename). What's the output of `namei -l "$(command -v rename)"`. It looks like you don't have the `rename` package installed, so whatever `rename` command you have probably doesn't come from Debian.

Comment: Debian has always (well for a long time anyway) shipped the dumb `rename` from util-linux as `rename.ul`. Do you  still have a command called `rename`? It just looks like you've uninstalled the `rename` package here.

Comment: I agree with @StéphaneChazelas - just do an `apt install rename` and see what you get.

Comment: I'm embarrassed... I've tried to `apt install rename` a while ago and I was told the like of `no such package' — of course I've made some sort of mistake.  Sorry for the noise and thank you Stéphane for the help.

Comment: Note that `rename` used to be shipped with `perl`. It was separated into its own package at some point, but that was a long time ago.

Comment: Actually, not so longer ago, sorry. So it's probably the source of your confusion.

Comment: The default rename utility, based on latest Ubuntu installs I'm using, shows rename has it's own package which uses File::Rename (PERL). So something is certainly amiss on your system. Try doing dpkg -l rename + post output. This will likely show how to fix the problem you're seeing.

Comment: @gboffi you can view with `apt-cache showpkg rename` and with `apt-cache policy rename` what you would get.